# Conditions for unique solution

Tags: probability, statistics

It might be too specific to be asked here, but anyway. I have the following simple equation,
$$
x-\Phi(\frac{k-x}{\sigma\sqrt{2}})=0
$$
where $\Phi(.)$ is cdf of the standard normal distribution.The question is, is this system has a unique solution? I have tried implicit function theorem but could not figure out how to conclude the answer is affirmative. Many thanks for every help!

P.S: I am trying to find solution as function of $k$. Say, we have unique solution $x*$ which is defined as function $b(k)$. So, I am also looking for properties of $b(k)$ like monotonicity or whatsoever

Comment: Are you only interested in real solutions (as opposed to complex)?

Comment: It seems straightforward that the function is increasing from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ hence...

Comment: @Raskolnikov: I am confused, since support of standard normal is real $x$ seems real to me.

Comment: @Did: I can't proceed with your argument. I can say that left-hand side is increasing with $x$ and decreasing with $k$ but that's it. Can you give proof or argument more clearly?

Comment: My first comment was rather clear, thank you. For every $\sigma\gt0$ and $k$ fixed, the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=x-\Phi((k-x)/\sigma\sqrt2)$ has a unique *root*, that is, there exists a unique $x$ such that $f(x)=0$. Existence: limits at $\pm\infty$ and IVT for continuous functions. Uniqueness: increasingness of $f$. Similarly, the function $k\mapsto x(k)$ is increasing because $\Phi$ is increasing.

Comment: @Did: Thanks, now it makes sense ad solution is neat enough, I should say!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For every $σ>0$ and $k$ fixed, the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=x−Φ((k−x)/σ\sqrt2)$ has a unique root, that is, there exists a unique $x$ such that $f(x)=0$. Existence: limits at ±∞ and IVT for continuous functions. Uniqueness: increasingness of $f$. Similarly, the function $k↦x(k)$ is increasing because $Φ$ is increasing.*

Let $x(k)$ denote the unique root of this equation, that is,
$$
x(k)=\Phi(a(k-x(k))),\qquad a=1/\sigma\sqrt2.
$$
Differentiating this yields
$$
x'(k)=a(1-x'(k))\varphi(a(k-x(k))),
$$
that is,
$$
x'(k)=\frac{a\varphi(a(k-x(k)))}{1+a\varphi(a(k-x(k)))}.
$$